# Unit testing with equivalence classes

Tags: unit-testing, testing

I'm currently testing a calculator application for a university assignment, I have identified 3 equivalence classes:

- Positive numbers
- Negative number
- Zero

When selecting a value of an equivalence class to use in a unit test, should the value be randomly generated or should the same value be used every time?

Comment: Please provide more comment or examples how you understand that question. What is 'equivalence class'?

Comment: @Rafik991 It is not specific information, you should know about it if you know about testing.

Comment: Now that question seems more readable for me. Thanks ;)

Comment: Hmm... I think that when you test something you should be sure about what it should be, so when you make assertion usually it should not be changed. In large systems unit tests are very desirable because of tons of code. So keep it simple and not generate random values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same numbers, that's the point of equivalence classes. If you've defined the classes well, it will do the job. Your classes for this problem seem ok to me in this sense.

On the other hand, tests with random numbers can be a good idea since it can help you **discover** new classes (maybe some classes you missed at first). Extra tests usually don't hurt, but make sure you still have non-random tests.